# Multithreading summing large number of values atomically

Tags: java, multithreading

I am developing an application where we have large number of threads and have to add 100's of values atomically. I am using `AtomicLong` which work well but still need to improve the performance. Is there something which offers better performance then AtomicLong?

Comment: What sort of number of threads? How many values per thread? If you are not doing this already, can you perhaps add up values *within* each thread using plain longs, then use `AtomicLong` only for summing values *between* threads?

Comment: Sounds like you may want to look at Javas fork/join framework or some map/reduce framework.

Comment: If you can implement a better solution than  http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.java by all means...

Comment: DNA's approach sounds best.  Though I have to ask, why are you worried about adding hundreds of values?  If you had to add billions of values, performance would be important.  If Java uses hardware atomics, adding 100s of values would still be cheaper than one single context-switch.

Comment: @aioobe Already looked at Fork/Join and it doesn't solve the problem. Map reduce framework like Hadoop is not an option due to internal project managment

Comment: @DNA hard to tell exact numberbecause values comes from stock exchange

Comment: @DNA not sure but it seems lot of contentation is the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [LongAdder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/LongAdder.html). LongAdder offer much better performance then AtomicLong. I would suggest reading [this](http://minddotout.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/java-8-concurrency-longadder/) article where the author published benchmarking results and explained quit many details regarding LongAdder performance. But in a nutshell `LongAdder` extends `Striped64` that handles contentation quit well by using hash table of cells. So when 2 threads try to put some value ,then there is good probability that both of them will end putting value in different cells. Cell class uses Padding stratergy to reduce CPU cache contentation. Moreover if you take a look on source code then you will find that cell class uses CAS.

> Unsafe.compareAndSwap operations are atomic. They take a pointer to a
>   chunk of memory (in this case comprised of this and valueOffset which
>   together point to value), a compare value and a swap value. If the JVM
>   finds that the value of the addressed memory is equal to the compare
>   value, then it stores the swap value in the addressed memory and
>   returns true. This means that CAS operations are a fast and thread
>   safe way to update the value of a variable and get feedback on whether
>   the operation was successful or whether there was contention.

Answer (score 1):

Section 15.3.2 of [JCIP](http://jcip.net.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/):

> at high contention levels locking tends to outperform atomic
>   variables, but at more realistic contention levels atomic variables
>   outperform locks.

You could either try a [back-off scheme](http://java.dzone.com/articles/wanna-get-faster-wait-bit) to improve the performance of your atomic variables or you could switch to using fully-fledged `ReentrantLock`s.