# What are LongAdders in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

In Java8 Oracle introduced a new Class LongAdder which seems to perform better than AtomicInteger under high contention. Some blog posts claim that LongAdder perform better by maintaining internal cells - does that mean LongAdder aggregates the values internally and update it later? Could you please help me to understand how LongAdder works?

Comment: [Relevant SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30691083/how-longadder-performs-better-than-atomiclong)